InterruptedIOException from OKHTTP client post java upgrade to 21 and Spring boot 3.3
We recently updated our APIs with Java 21(Eclipse Temurin; open JDK) and with Spring Boot 3.3. And also enabled the virtual threads
spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true

After this, we continuously get InterruptedIOException from HttpClient. Below is the stacktrace of the log; please check and suggest if there is any configuration required to control the exceptions.
Note: I have not created any custom connection pools for HttpClient
java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.timeoutExit(RealCall.kt:398)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.callDone(RealCall.kt:360)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.noMoreExchanges$okhttp(RealCall.kt:325)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:209)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: CANCEL
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.checkOutNotClosed$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:646)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.emitFrame(Http2Stream.kt:557)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.close(Http2Stream.kt:612)
at okio.ForwardingSink.close(ForwardingSink.kt:37)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$RequestBodySink.close(Exchange.kt:247)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.close(RealBufferedSink.kt:287)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:63)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
... 4 more
Suppressed: okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException`your text`: stream was reset: CANCEL
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:148)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:97)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:110)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallSer… [message truncated due to size]

HttpClient configuration is like below
OkHttpClient httpClient = OkHttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .withConnectTimeout(10)
                    .withReadTimeout(10)
                    .build();           

I am not able to reproduce this in a local machine and hard to know from it is coming. So, reaching out to get help to resolve the issue.

Is the issue reproducible if you set spring.threads.virtual.enabled=false? Also I don't see any sigh of virtual thread involved in your stack trace. You might also want to post complete stack trace instead of this cut-out one, here or somewhere else.

Yes; issue is not related to virtual threads. We found out that it is due to java telemetry agent; disabling it; solved the problem. Thanks for the reply.

Thanks for letting know. Might make sense to remove virtual-threads tag.
